# PostgreSQL connection timeout

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am using a desktop application with PostgreSQL database server. When I am not using application for **10 to 20 minutes** continuously, the database **connection is dropped**. And I am using **PostgresqlJDBC** for database connection.

Please help me on this to database connection time out.

Thanks.

Comment: I know its a desktop-app but beside this: using Tomcats JNDI datasources its the XML-Parameter `<Resource ... maxWait="1" ... >` for connection. I also use a Map<Session,Exception> to log where sessions has never closed.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are connected via a stateful connection tracking router/firewall that has a short connection tracking timeout. Sounds like you need to enable keepalives.

Take a look at the [`tcp_keepalives_interval` and `tcp_keepalives_idle` parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html).

You can also request keepalives client-side in the JDBC driver; see the pgJDBC docs.

Comment: Thank you.
I will look into pgJDBC docs.
Can you please tell me the (best and optimized) values for both the parameters?

Comment: If there was a single value that was right for everybody, it would not be a parameter. It depends on your environment - how often the timeouts occur, etc.