# why does spring-boot and postgres connection breaks after certain time?

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, spring-boot

I run Spring-Boot with gradle using the tomcat-connection-pool. All the standard spring-boot-tools. I run several soap-webservices on that webserver. It all works fine when testing the load of the server. But after a doing nothing for ~7.5hours this exception occurs. Sure its a `timeout` but I try to prevent it with the following:

- `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://mydb?autoReconnect=true`
- I use `@transactional` for certain statements. But in general I only use the `JPA-Repository` from spring-boot.
- The connections are managed by the tomcat-connection-pool so there is no idle-connection-problem.
- When I restart the application-server everything runs fine again.

My Database-server runs `PostgreSQL 9.4.1 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` and there is NO firewall between the database and the app-server.

Do I need [tcp_keep alives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296601/postgresql-connection-timeout)?

**Why does my connection breaks after a certain time and is no more recoverable?**

My App-properties:

```
#
# [ Database Configuration Section ]
#
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy

spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://*****:5434/******
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****

logging.file=*******.log
logging.level.=WARNING
```

---

```
2015-09-29 11:58:50.598  INFO 10498 --- [nio-9092-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-09-29 11:58:50.598  INFO 10498 --- [nio-9092-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2015-09-29 11:58:50.674  INFO 10498 --- [nio-9092-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 76 ms
```

---

```
2015-09-29 19:23:03.777  WARN 10498 --- [ool-3-thread-16] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
2015-09-29 19:23:03.779 ERROR 10498 --- [ool-3-thread-16] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
2015-09-29 19:23:03.785  INFO 10498 --- [ool-3-thread-16] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2015-09-29 19:23:03.836 ERROR 10498 --- [ool-3-thread-16] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Commit exception overridden by rollback exception
java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:143) ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:112) ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:71) ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:282) ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1718) ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173) ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:201) ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:615) ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:465) ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:411) ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute statement
```

*EDIT:*

I've added this and testing it currently:

```
  spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
  spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

And removed `autoReconnect`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22687418/3093580
above answer may be useful

Comment: trying this one - takes 7.5 hours - you get a response tomorrow :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by @Yuki Yoshida the answer was that simple.

I added
`spring.datasource.validation-query= select 1`
`spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true`
to my configuration and it works.

Test-on-borrow:

> testOnBorrow: Default: true
>
> The indication of whether objects will be validated
>   before being borrowed from the pool. If the object fails to validate,
>   it will be dropped from the pool, and we will attempt to borrow
>   another.

And 
validationQuery: Default: for most db languages `select 1`  else see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases)

> validationQuery
>
> The SQL query that will be used to validate
>   connections from this pool before returning them to the caller. If
>   specified, this query MUST be an SQL SELECT statement that returns at
>   least one row. If not specified, connections will be validation by
>   calling the isValid() method.

I actually tried this already but I did not explicitly set test-on-borrow to true because of its default. Looks like you have to set it explicitly.

Comment: isValid() implemented by default? to test the connection. if possible can u share the implementation details

Comment: Dear Ramakrishnan, yes - isValid is implemented by default. Please see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjucp/validating-ucp-connections.html#GUID-39E5A876-8C54-423F-B6A7-5E827DE202C7 for more details about the isValid() usage.